# What is the method to solve this kind of problems in modular arithmetic?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

*x is a three-digit natural number,*

$$2x \equiv 3 \pmod 5$$

$$3x \equiv 1 \pmod 4 $$

**what is the smallest value that x can take?**

What is the method to solve this kind of questions?

Comment: Maybe first rewrite our congruences as $x\equiv 4\pmod{5}$, $x\equiv 3\pmod{4}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas  And then what? I guess I am just stupid...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem

Comment: I was just about to post that. In particular, you want this section: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Finding_the_solution_with_basic_algebra_and_modular_arithmetic

Comment: Multiplying by the inverses of the lead coefs yields the equivalent system $\,x\equiv -1\,$ both $\bmod 5\ \&\ 4\,$ which is equivalent to $x\equiv -1\pmod{20}\,$ by  linked CCRT (or generally, by [Easy CRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2006919/242). See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3623942/242) for a fractional generalization of CRT.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, you can use the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), but in a case like this, you can probably just guess and check because the congruences are small.

Let's find the smallest solution to $2x \equiv 3 \pmod 5$. Looks like $4,9,14,19,24$ works so $x \equiv 4 \pmod 5$ is a solution.

Let's do the same thing for $3x \equiv 1 \pmod 4$. Looks like $3, 7, 11, 15, 19$ works so $x \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ is a solution.

Thus the smallest such solution looks to be $x = 19$. If you want a higher number (not sure why you would want a specific 3-digit number, but that's not important), you can use the general congruences.

Comment: $13$ is not a solution to $2x\equiv3\bmod5$, nor to $3x\equiv1\bmod4$, nor is it a three-digit number (as requested by OP).

Comment: Good catch, looks like I was going to fast trying to get the mortarboard badge, haha. I have edited my post.