# CRT solvability for congruence systems of fraction form $\ a_i x\equiv b_i\pmod{\!m_i}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations, chinese-remainder-theorem

I have to see for which value of $a$ this system is solvable:
$$
\begin{cases}
  3x \equiv a\pmod{28}\\
  ax \equiv4\pmod{21}\\
\end{cases}
$$
I check the two congruences separately:
$$
\gcd(3,28)=1\mid a\;\checkmark
$$
$$
\gcd(a,21)\mid4 \iff \gcd(a, 21) = 1 \iff a \not\equiv 0\;(7)\;\land a \not\equiv 0\;(3)
$$

$$
\begin{cases}
  3x \equiv a\pmod{4}\\
  ax \equiv4\pmod{3}\\
\end{cases}\\ \gcd(4,3) = 1\;\checkmark
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
  3x \equiv a\pmod{7}\\
  ax \equiv4\pmod{7}\\
\end{cases}
$$
and from here I can't go on.

So, my problem is that I can't figure out how to check if a system of congruences is solvable.

EDIT:

maybe I found the solution:
$
\gcd(7,7) = 7\mid a-4 \iff a = 11+7k \land a \not\equiv 0\;(7)$

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120070/chinese-remainder-theorem-with-non-pairwise-coprime-moduli) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3121135/chinese-remainder-theorem-solvability-for-non-coprime-moduli)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no $a$ for which the system is solvable. By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, 
$$
3x \equiv a \pmod{28} \\
ax \equiv 4 \pmod{21}
$$
is equivalent to solving:
$$
3x \equiv a \pmod{7} \\
3x \equiv a \pmod{4} \\
ax \equiv 4 \pmod{7} \\
ax \equiv 4 \pmod{3} \\
$$

Note that the first equations tells us $x \equiv 5a \pmod{7}$, and the third equation tell us $5a^{2} \equiv 4 \pmod{7} \implies a^{2} \equiv 5 \pmod{7}$, but $5$ is not a quadratic residue mod $7$. The quadratic residue are $1,2,4$ mod $7$. Hence, there is no solution. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: it is not clear to me how you went from $3x \equiv a\;(mod\;7)$ to $x \equiv 5a\;(mod\;7)$

Comment: You have to observe that since $3$ is not zero in $\mathbb{Z} / 7\mathbb{Z}$, it is invertible with inverse $5 \pmod{7}$. Multiplying by $5$ on both sides yields the latter equation. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: It is difficult for me to calculate congruences "by eye", so I usually do this:
$$
3x≡a\;(mod\;7)\\
3x-7y = a \\
x_0 = -2a,\;y_0 = -1a\\
x = -2a+7t\\
x≡-2a\;(mod\;7)\\
x≡5a\;(mod\;7)\\
$$

$$
5a^2≡4\;(mod\;7) \rightarrow 5a≡4\;(mod\;7)\\
5a-7y = 4 \\
a_0 = 12,\;y_0 = 8\\
a≡12\;(mod\;7)\\
a≡5\;(mod\;7)\rightarrow a^2≡5\;(mod\;7)
$$
I have never seen a quadratic congruence with the form $ax^2$, so I wonder if what I did is correct and if there is any condition to consider.

Comment: Your implications $5a^{2} \equiv 4 \pmod{7} \implies 5a \equiv 4 \pmod{7}$ and $a \equiv 5 \pmod{7} \implies a^{2} \equiv 5 \pmod{7}$ are not correct. In your second paragraph, if you replace $a$ with $a^{2}$ then your calculation is correct. Perhaps this is what you're doing, but it is not clear. Your methodology seems right, but in general for a prime $p$, there is always a multiplicative inverse to a non-zero element, so if you can find the inverse the calculations will be faster. Let me know if you have further questions, else could you accept an answer?

Answer (score 4):

Below we show how to reduce it to the [well-known CRT solvability condition](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2060729/242), and that it has a very  intuitive natural interpretation in terms of **modular fraction equivalence**. Our system is

$$\begin{align} &\color{#90f}3x \equiv a\!\!\pmod{28}\\
               &\color{#0a0}{\color{#c00}ax} \color{#0a0}{\equiv 4\!\!\pmod{\color{#c00}{21}}}  \end{align}\qquad$$

[Recall](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3290965/242) if $\,\color{#0a0}{\color{#c00}a\:\!x+\color{#c00}{21}\:\!y = 4}\,$ is solvable then $\,\color{#c00}{g := (a,21)}\mid \color{#0a0}4\,$ so $\,g\mid 21,4\Rightarrow \color{#c00}{g=1}.\,$ So by Theorem below the system is solvable $\!\iff\!\bmod 7\!:\ a\color{#c00}a\equiv \color{#90f}3\cdot\color{#0a0} 4\equiv -2\,\overset{\rm cube}\Rightarrow a^{\large 6}\equiv -1,\,$ contra lil Fermat.

**Theorem** $\ $ If $\,(a,m) = \color{#c00}{1 = (c,n)}\,$ then

$$\exists\, x\!:\ \begin{align} 
&\color{#90f}ax\equiv b\!\!\pmod{\!m}\\
&\:\!\color{#0a0}{\color{#c00}cx}\color{#0a0}{\equiv d\!\!\pmod{\!\color{#c00}n}}\end{align}
\iff \color{#90f}a\color{#0a0}d\equiv b\color{#c00}c\!\!\pmod{(m,n)}\qquad$$

**Proof** $\ $ By hypotheses and [Bezout:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3290965/242) $\,a^{-1}$ exists mod $m\,$ and $\,c^{-1}$ exists mod $n,\,$ so

$$\exists\, x\!:\ \begin{align} ax&\equiv b\!\!\pmod{\!m}\\cx&\equiv d\!\!\pmod{\!n}\end{align}\iff \exists\, x\!:\!\!\!\!\!\begin{array}{} &x\equiv b/a\,\pmod{\!m}\\&x\equiv d/c\: \pmod{\!n}\end{array}\quad$$

By the [well-known CRT solvability criterion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2060729/242) the prior system is solvable  iff

$$\bmod (m,n)\!:\,\ b/a\equiv x \equiv d/c\!\!\overset{\times\ ac\!}\iff bc\equiv ad$$

where we used $\,(a,(m,n)) = 1 = (c,(m,n))\, $ by $(a,m) = 1 = (c,n),\,$ therefore scaling by the units (invertibles) $\,a,c\,$ [yields an *equivalent* congruence](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3461547/242) $\bmod (m,n)$.

**Remark** $ $ This solvability criterion is much more intuitive in *fractional* language, where it becomes the modular version of the cross-multiplication test for modular fraction equivalence, i.e.

$$\exists\, x\!:\ \begin{align} x&\equiv \frac{b}a\!\!\pmod{\!m}\\[.2em]x&\equiv \frac{d}c\!\!\pmod{\!n}\end{align}\!\iff \frac{b}a\equiv \frac{d}c\!\! \pmod{\!(m,n)}\qquad$$

This is a natural fractional extension of the said CRT solvability criterion (it is a version of CRT in the ring of fractions writable with denominator coprime to to both $m$ and $n$, a fundamental construction whose properties are developed at length when one studies commutative algebra).

Comment: "Cubing" to get a lil Fermat contradiction is a special case of square-testing via [Euler's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion).

Answer (score 1):

$3x \equiv a \bmod 7$ and $ax \equiv 4 \bmod 7$ imply $3x^2 \equiv 4 \bmod 7$ or $x^2 \equiv -1 \bmod 7$. There is no such $x$.